# how to set image in toast notification in windows 8.1 app using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I am trying to set an image in notification in windows 8.1 application using c# but unable do so can only see the text.Can someone help with the following code.
Following is code:

```
ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01;
 XmlDocument toastXml =ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("test"));


XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/download.png"); //30X30
((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "test");


IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

 ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
 ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Comment: I thought `ToastTemplateType` was a win10 thing only?

Comment: did you try using an absolute local path? the option which starts with "ms-appdata:///local..."